# Cannot rotate / transcode video with any tool

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-emulator, video-encoding

I have a video captured from Android Virtual Device (Android Emulator). Its format is WebM. I need to rotate it 90 degrees counterclockwise. But I can't do this: I have tried FFMpeg - it drops ALL frames except 1-2, several online converters - no result. Then, I"ve tried to encode this video to H.264... no result. Whole video is black (there can be 1-2 frames, again). How can I rotate or reencode this video?

Video: https://dropmefiles.com/nhy0H (untitled.webm - video needs to be rotated; out_example.webm - output video from FFMpeg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, ffmpeg is detecting the wrong frame rate (0.04 fps) - either malformed header or demuxer bug. So, during transcode, a corresponding timebase is chosen, which causes DTS resolution to be very coarse, which in turn causes ffmpeg to drop most frames.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i untitled.webm -vf transpose=2 -time_base:v 1/1000 -c:a copy out.webm
```